# How to run console application when other project build is failing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I have a console application that doesn't depend on the other project in the solution.  The other project build is failing (compile issue), and I don't want to fix it just yet.

How can I get the console application to run?  I have already set the console project as the 'startup project'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no dependencies you can go to the Build menu at the top, and select "Configuration Manager".  Find the project you do not want to build and make sure the checkbox in the "Build" column is *not* checked.

Alternatively you could right click the console app and choose "Debug -> Start New Instance".

This assumes that there are no dependencies between projects.

Comment: thanks, start new instance is what I was looking, never saw that before!

Answer (score 2):

You can unload other projects, and then start your debug process in visual studio.

Example:

[image: Example: To unload the project]

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one other project in the solution, an easy fix would be to right click on that other project and simply "Unload Project".

Answer (score -1):

> right click on the project itself -> debug -> start new instance